# $\bigcup^n_{i=1} \mathcal{P} (E_i) \subseteq \mathcal{P} (\bigcup^n_{i=1}E_i)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Given some sets $E_1,...,E_n$, prove that

$$\bigcup^n_{i=1} \mathcal{P} (E_i) \subseteq \mathcal{P} \left(\bigcup^n_{i=1}E_i\right)$$

I don't know if my proof is valid:

Given an arbitrary $x \in \bigcup^n_{i=1} \mathcal{P} (E_i) \Rightarrow \exists E_j :x \subseteq E_j \Rightarrow x \subseteq \bigcup^n_{i=1}E_i \Rightarrow x \in \mathcal{P}(\bigcup_{i=1}^nE_i)$

Comment: What is $P$ in this question?

Comment: Power set, my bad

Comment: Your proof looks right to me.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea! Well done!

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  I'd quibble about where the $E_j$ sprang from, and suggest adding an extra step right at the start, but the proof is convincing.

$$\begin{array}{|l}\quad\begin{array}{|ll}x \in \bigcup^n_{i=1} \mathcal{P} (E_i)&\text{by supposition for arbitrary }x\\\hline\exists i\in [n].x\in\mathcal P(E_i)&\text{by definition of union series.}\\\exists i\in [n].x\subseteq E_i&\text{by definition of powerset.}\\x\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i&\text{by definition of union series.}\\x\in\mathcal P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i)&\text{by definition of powerset.}\end{array}\\\therefore~\bigcup_{i=1}^n\mathcal P(E_i)\subseteq \mathcal P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i)\end{array}$$